# How to query a Twitter timeline in parallel?

Tags: twitter

I am building a Twitter app and I'll be pulling a big amount of data from the user's timeline. For speed, I need to query the timeline in parallel. My aim is to pull 1000 of user's tweets from the API, but the upper limit of number of tweets per request is set to 200 by the Twitter API. Pagination works by specifying the last (oldest) tweet's ID from the previous request, so I need to know the result of the previous API call to make the next call. This method is not parallelizable. Is there any alternative method for getting the user timeline from the Twitter API where I can make parallel requests (there is the `page` property, but is deprecated and will be nonfunctional in the near future).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to remember, is that Twitter have a difficult relationship with external developers.  Using their API for anything interesting like this is simply not allowed by them.

What you need is access to the [Firehose](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/2752).

However, [even if you're willing to pay a million dollars a year](http://techcrunch.com/2012/12/04/peoplebrowsr-says-twitter-changed-position-on-eve-of-discovery-battle-twitter-wants-federal-jurisdiction/) - Twitter aren't interested.

You could try getting it from a third party like [Gnip](http://gnip.com/) but - again - likely to be expensive.

So, essentially, you can't.  Twitter just aren't interested in amateur developers doing anything innovative with their platform.  Sorry.

Comment: sad to see twitter's this policy *against* developers.